# Close modal without animation

Tags: ios, swift

I have a modal segue. In the `Storyboard segue` from the `Attributes inspector` I uncheck the `Animates` option and to dismiss the `UIViewController` inside a `UINavigationController` I'm doing this:

```
self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

But it stills doing the top to bottom animation to close.

Is anyway to close a modal without animation?

Comment: Are you calling `dismiss` from the presenting or the presented view controller? If the latter, can you try `self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)`?

Comment: @XML I call `dismiss` from the `presentingViewController` and it works

Comment: that's good to hear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I have to do to close the modal `UIViewController` inside a `UINavigationController` without animation:

```
self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```