# Is there a way to dismiss a modal view without animation in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, modal-dialog, swiftui

### Is there a way to dismiss a modal view without animation in SwiftUI?

I want to dismiss a modal without the dismiss animation because I want to navigate from the modal view to a new SwiftUI View using a view router. Everything is working, except for the transition animation from the modal view to the new full-screen view. I followed that tutorial to create a view router: [Tutorial](https://blckbirds.com/post/how-to-navnigate-between-views-in-swiftui-by-using-an-environmentobject/))

I'm using that code snippet to present the modal view:

```
struct ContentView: View {

  @State private var showModal = false
  @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode


  var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        self.showModal = true
    }) {
        Text("Show modal")
    }.sheet(isPresented: self.$showModal) {
        ModalView()
    }
  }
}


struct ModalView: View {

  @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter

  var body: some View {
    Group {
      Text("Modal view")
      Button(action: {
         self.viewRouter.currentPage = "New View"
      }) {
        Text("Dismiss")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Source: [Answer by @M Reza Farahani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56563652/8642838)

Here is a solution in Swift: [Swift solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44079529/close-modal-without-animation)

Comment: did you manage to fix this? I also cant dismiss the modal without the default animation

Answer (score 1):

Did not fully test this since I dont have the ViewRouter

You should move the

```
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
```

the ModalView and add

```
self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
```

to the button action in that ModalView

Edit:

After I added

```
.animation(.none)
```

To the ModalView it worked for me

Alright thats one ugly a** comment so putting it here:

```
    struct ModalView: View {

//  @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

  var body: some View {
    Group {
      Text("Modal view")
      Button(action: {
//         self.viewRouter.currentPage = "New View"
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()

      }) {
        Text("Dismiss")
      }
    }
    .animation(.none)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But then I still have that transition animation. That'll not fix my problem with the animation.

Comment: When i add .animation(.none) to the ModalView it does not have an animation anymore. Hopefully that gives you the desired effect.

Comment: @Great Otten Where do you add the ``` .animation(.none) ```modifier? I'm not exactly sure how to fix that issue.

Comment: Ah my bad. Should have been more clear. Edited my comment above.

Comment: Unfortunately, dismissing the modal is still animated

Comment: Ah that is weird. I tested it on a simulator and I think it gives the result you want, but when i build it on my real device it does still animate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215573/discussion-between-geart-otten-and-jonas-deichelmann).

Comment: @GeartOtten I am also unable to dismiss without animation. Can you please guide?

Comment: @Tul I've tried with the solution above, but it only seems to work on simulators and not real devices. I am not sure how to fix it correctly.

Comment: This, among other things, showcases feature incompleteness of SwiftUI, and why it pains me that I now have to support an iOS app where the previous developer chose this non-production ready technology.  I guess it's ready for some simpler apps, but my client is constantly asking for customizations in areas like this that SwiftUI just can't do yet.